# Maximal angle distortion by positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

**The question(s):**

If $A$ is a positive definite matrix, what unit vector(s) $x$ have their angle the most distorted by $A$? How much is the angle changed? More formally, what is
\begin{equation} \tag{Q1}
\text{argmin}_{|x|=1} \left \langle \frac{Ax}{|Ax|}, x \right \rangle
\end{equation}
and what is
\begin{equation} \tag{Q2}
\min_{|x|=1} \left \langle \frac{Ax}{|Ax|}, x \right \rangle?
\end{equation}

**Some Motivation:**

If $A$ is a positive definite matrix, we know it's smallest eigenvalue, $\lambda_{\min}$ is strictly posiitve. In particular,
\begin{equation} \tag{1}
\left\langle \frac{Ax}{|x|}, \frac{x}{|x|} \right\rangle \ge \lambda_{\min} .
\end{equation}

Since we also know $\langle Ax, x \rangle = |Ax| |x| \cos(\theta) \ge \lambda_{\min} |x|^{2}$ (where $\theta$ is the angle between $x$ and $Ax$) a popular geometric interpretation of "$A$ is positive definite" is that the angle between $x$ and $Ax$ is less than $\pi/2$.

Alas, the (unit) vector which minimizes (1) is precisely the (unit) eigenvector corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue, let's call it $x_{\min}$. When we plug $x_{\min}$ into (Q2) and compute, we find
$$
\left \langle \frac{Ax_{\min}}{|Ax_{\min}|}, \frac{x_{\min}}{|x_{\min}|} \right \rangle = \left \langle \frac{\lambda_{\min} x_{\min}}{|\lambda_{\min}|}, x_{\min} \right \rangle= 1 = \cos(\theta).
$$
So, the angle between $x_{\min}$ and $Ax_{\min}$ is actually zero.

**A bad estimate for (Q2) and consequent conjecture:**

The best estimate I can think of for (Q2) is probably an extremely poor estimate. Namely, using $|Ax| \le \lambda_{\max} |x|$ and $\langle Ax, x \rangle \ge \lambda_{\min} |x|^{2}$ yields the estimate
$$
\min_{|x|=1} \left \langle \frac{Ax}{|Ax|}, x \right \rangle \ge \frac{\lambda_{\min}}{\lambda_{\max}}.
$$
However, the vectors that achieve the two bounds I used are the eigenvectors corresponding to the largest and smallest eigenvectors ($x_{\max}$ and $x_{\min}$). But, $x_{\max} \cdot x_{\min} = 0$, i.e., they are not very close to the same vector, and as in the "Motivation" section, plugging either of these into (Q2) we actually get the value $1$.

This gives me a wild guess, that choosing the vector $\frac{x_{\max} + x_{min}}{|x_{\max} + x_{\min}|}$ would be a good candidate answer for (Q1). Considering this, we compute (assuming $|x_{\max}| = 1 = |x_{\min}|$)
\begin{align*}
\left \langle \frac{A(x_{\max} + x_{\min})}{|A(x_{\max}+x_{min})|}, \frac{x_{\max} + x_{\min}}{\sqrt{2}} \right \rangle &= \left \langle \frac{ \lambda_{\max} x_{\max} + \lambda_{\min} x_{\min}}{|\lambda_{\max} x_{\max} + \lambda_{\min} x_{\min}|}, \frac{x_{\max} + x_{\min}}{\sqrt{2}} \right \rangle \\
& = \frac{\lambda_{\max} + \lambda_{\min}}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{ \lambda_{\max}^{2} + \lambda_{\min}^{2}}}.
\end{align*}

But, I have no idea how to check if this actually achieves the minimum.

**An equivalent statement:**

After continuing to think about this and some other related questions, I have in other questions had success due to an observation along the lines of what follows.

Suppose $|x| = 1$ and for simplicity, re-scale $A$ so that $|Ax| = 1$ as well. Then, $$1 - \langle Ax,x \rangle = \frac{|Ax -x|^{2}}{2}.$$ So questions (Q1) and (Q2) (after undoing the previous re-scaling of $A$) can be equivalently re-stated as questions about minimizing over $|x| = 1$ the function
$$
1 - \frac{\left|\frac{Ax}{|Ax|} - x \right|^{2}}{2}.
$$

At first glance this seems more convenient for trying to use a Lagrange to determine the minimum.